# Problems with web scraping phantom js?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape html from a webpage using [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/api/) but then I am getting this strange error. When I run the script once, I am getting the correct response, but then when I try again, I am getting no response.

It looks like its loading forever. I don't want to call `phantom.exit()` as it stops the server. So, what could I be doing wrong?

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    server = require('webserver').create();

var service = server.listen(8003, function (request, response) {

    console.log('Request received at ' + new Date());

    // TODO: parse `request` and determine where to go
    page.open('https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/?sportId=1&league=76080&leagueName=la%20liga&top=0',function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var test = page.plainText
            console.log(page.plainText);
            response.write(page.plainText)
            response.close();
            page.close();
        })
    })

});
```

Comment: Is `console.log('Request` firing the second time? If so, I'd confirm that `page.open(` is finishing the second time. Might not since it's the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are closing the page after the first time and then attempting to reuse it again. [Per the docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html), you should not do this

> Close the page and releases the memory heap associated with it. **Do not use the page instance after calling this.**

Try recreating the `page` object upon each request, like so:

```js
var webpage = require('webpage'),
    server = require('webserver').create();

var service = server.listen(8003, function (request, response) {

    console.log('Request received at ' + new Date());

    let page = webpage.create()
    
    // TODO: parse `request` and determine where to go
    page.open('https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/?sportId=1&league=76080&leagueName=la%20liga&top=0',function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var test = page.plainText
            console.log(page.plainText);
            response.write(page.plainText)
            response.close();
            page.close();
        })
    })

});
```